# Android: How to make a Spinner invisible and then visible again?

Tags: android

I have the following `Spinner`:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
```

and I initially make it invisible like this:

```
spinner.setVisibility(TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND);
```

This does make the `Spinner` invisible but how to make it visible again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

//Hide

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

//Show

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change via xml code

// HIDE

```
  android:visibility="invisible"
```

//SHOW

```
  android:visibility="visible"
```

// i am not sure about this one, it too hides, but why we have this, anyone can clear me?

```
  android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: 'invisible' still takes place even it disappears. 'gone' disappear and don't take place